# Many to Many, where rows are mapped to entire tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I am storing high-frequency financial data in the db. I would like to create a table, where each financial contract is mapped to tables with timeseries data.

In other words, I don't want to point to (many) specific rows in another table, but to many whole tables. Example:

```
Contract A - table "A_January2021_data"
Contract B - table "B_February2018_data"
Contract C - table "C_May1994_data"
Contract C - table "C_October2000_data"
```

I would like to use that table later to pull timeseries data from relevant tables, i.e. for Contract C, get all data from tables `C_May1994_data`, `C_October2000_data`.

Is that possible with idiomatic SQL? Equally importantly, is this a good idea?

Comment: *is this a good idea?*: I don't think it is. Have a single table to store this data, and then you can use simple relations and queries.

Comment: My concern with the approach you suggest is that I will need another column to describe the contract for each row. With a very large number of rows, it may consume a lot of space. Right now, the contract identifier is stored in the table name. Can you think of a way to alleviate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a good idea?: I don't think it is.

I would recommend a single table to store the timeseries data, and a referential table to store the contrats. You can then link both tables together through a foreign key constraint.

```
create table contracts (
    contract_id serial primary key,
    -- other contract master data here
);

create table data_series (
    date_series_id serial primary key,
    ts timestamp not null,
    contract_id int references contracts(contract_id),
    -- other time series here
);
```

The overhead that you get by adding an integer column to the data table is rather tiny, and it makes your schema much easier to manipulate that creating a table per contract (which will probably force you to use dynamic SQL at some point later on).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that contracts can be linked with timeseries via integer/id. I was stuck on using the ticker (string) but it doesn't make sense now that you mentioned using an id.